# create multiple columns in R from one row

Tags: r, multiple-columns

basically I have 1 column with 5830 rows. Each row lists 15 numbers but I need each number in a separate column. Currently it looks like this:

```
sidno.cigsday1.cig1c.cursmk1.evsmk1.agesmk1.alcwkc1.curalc1.alc1c.highalc1.alc24hr1.age1c.gender1.htcm1.wtlb1
1   10001 10 1 0 1 15 5 1 2 1 1 58 1 171.6 150.4
2   10003 NA 0 0 0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA 47 0 163.1 212.5
3   10004 NA 0 0 0 NA 5 1 2 2 1 65 0 162.3 132.7
4   10005 NA 0 0 0 NA NA 0 1 NA NA 73 1 167.1 180.7
5   10006 4 1 0 1 18 NA 0 1 NA NA 67 1 159 210.2
6   10007 20 1 0 1 20 NA NA 0 NA NA 45 1 171 177
```

Comment: as richard mentions in his answer, `read.table('path/to/file.txt', header = TRUE)` looks like it would work on your original text file. maybe you used `read.csv` or `read.table(..., sep = ',')` or some other non whitespace separator ?